# Centering on the decimal separator, figure font selection

Tags: tables, siunitx, dcolumn

I'd like to format a column with numbers with a decimal point. In my body text I use old-style figures for numbers, and lining figures in equations. If I use `dcolumn` my tables use lining figures, instead of old-style figures.

I've fiddled around with the definitions in `dcolumn.sty` already, but it seems to rely on math mode to get the dot 'right', so removing all the `$`-characters leads to breakage.
Temporarily changing the math font to use old-style figures seems to be a pretty difficult thing as well, this is all set up during the loading of the font package...

Using `siunitx` with `\sisetup{mode=text}` I *do* get old-style figures, but then `\figureversion{tab}`, which I use to switch to tabular figures, is ignored, and the figures also don't line up nicely.

Does anyone have a good suggestion to either use `dcolumn` in non-math mode, or to get `siunitx` to use old-style tabular figures?

A minimal example, using siunitx:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[mathlf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=text}
\begin{document}
{\figureversion{tab}
  \begin{tabular}{SSS[table-format=4.1]}
    {A wide heading} & $x$ & {more data} \\
    14.1 & 14.1 & 1111.1 \\
    1.674 & 1.671 & 4882.8 \\
  \end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal example? In particular, what font package are you using?

Comment: MinionPro, I've added an example using siunitx, for completeness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{dcolumn}  

\makeatletter  


\newcolumntype{O}[3]{>{\everymath{\mathgroup\symletters}\DC@{#1}{#2}{#3}}c<{\DC@end}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{cO..{-1}D..{-1}}
zzzz & 1.1 & 1.1\\
zzzz & 1.12 & 1.12\\
zzzz & 2341.1 & 2341.1\\
zzzz & 1.1043 & 1.1043
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, excellent. I did not know about `\everymath{\mathgroup\symletters}`. This fixes the problem quite nicely, so I'll accept this answer. Using `siunitx` seems a bit like overkill just to format the columns, but still, if someone has a solution using `siunitx` it would be nice to see it.

Answer (score 5):

In the comment on David's earlier answer, you express interest in seeing a solution that uses the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type. The key is to specify the option `detect-mode`, which forces the use of the number style of the *text font* rather than of the math font.

The answer below uses the `kpfonts` package with the `oldstylenums` option to use old-style numbers in text mode; the body of the `tabular` environment is the same as in David's answer. The

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts} % oldstyle tabular numbers in text mode, but not in math mode
\usepackage[table-format=4.4]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cS[detect-mode]S}
zzzz & 1.1 & 1.1\\
zzzz & 1.12 & 1.12\\
zzzz & 2341.1 & 2341.1\\
zzzz & 1.1043 & 1.1043
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this not give nonproportional figures in the table? The text uses nonproportional old style figures, the table should use proportional (tabular) old style figures. An option would be to switch to proportional before the tabular environment begins, maybe.

Comment: @Michel - I'm not sure I understood your question fully. The example above, which uses the `kpfonts` font family under pdfLaTeX, generates tabular oldstyle *and* lining-style numbers, as tabular (proportional) figures is what the `kpfonts` family provides. Other font families may behave differently. I'm afraid I don't have access to the Minion Pro font, so I can't tell if that font behaves differently. For ultimate control over these issues, you may want to use employ either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and avail yourself of the capabilities of the `fontspec` package.